# String.format in JSP

Tags: string, jsp, format

How can I obtain the same behavior as String.format(String, Object ...) in a JSP(x) page?
Is there a tag library / function library yet available for this purpose?
I need something that given a source string and a set of arguments performs the substitutions like

```
<ns:tag source="Hi {0} {1}" arguments="'name','surname'" />
```

or

```
${ns:func("Hi {0} {1}", "'name','surname'")}
```

that results in

```
Hi name surname
```

Thanks you for any suggestion,
Stefano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the JSTL `<fmt:message>` tag:

```
<fmt:message key="the.message.key">
    <fmt:param value="name"/>
    <fmt:param value="surname"/>
</fmt:message>
```

It uses `java.text.MessageFormat` internally, though.

Most UI frameworks also have their own version of such a tag.